# Getting a list of dependencies from the optimizer backwards in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to generate a list of all dependencies from the optimizer backwards in tensorflow. My goal is to validate some assign operations were picked up correctly. Is there a straightforward way to generate such a graph?